# angularjs update a single element from a huge list

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi i am new to angularjs. I am using angular version 1.
I have and application which plays music over http.

So it basically displays thousands of songs in a list as thumbnail in which each tile contain play/pause buttons.
Also there is a footer on mini player which contain play/pause/next buttons

So my requirement is that how to switch the play/pause buttons on tile from this huge list.

Right now i am assigning track id as id for each tile and update the element by switching class with jquery. It takes too much time to update the list.

Can anyone tell me the best solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

here is my sample code

```
var item = $('.pause-btn')

    $('.pause-btn').removeClass('pause-btn')

    $('div').find("[data-index='" + btoa('track_' + CurrentSongId) + "']").addClass('pause-btn')
```

Comment: Can you please add some more code or provide a plunker?

Comment: You could share the play/pause buttons to each song, for instance have a play/pause component in the footer. Then you need to store the current song `id` somewhere it can be accessed by the footer, in a service maybe. And then when you click play/pause, you just need to get this particular `id` and do your actions.

Comment: @rocketer I didnt get that.Can you explain once more

Comment: You can have one angular component that is your thumbnail and switches between the song. Every time you switch the song, you store the id of the song somewhere. For that you can use angular service https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services. Then you can have another component which contains the play/pause buttons. When you click on it, it retrieves the id from the service. That's more a architecture idea than a code implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following sample

```
    <div>
    <p class=track.isPlaying==true?'pause':'play' ng-click=update(track)>
    <img src="albumart.jpeg">
    </p>
    </div>


//on controiller
    $scope.update=function(track)
    {
    track.isPlaying=!track.isPlaying
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you sample codes have nothing to do with angularjs , i guess you may want to achieve something like this:

```
$('div')
.find("[data-index='" + btoa('track_' + CurrentSongId) + "']")
.addClass('pause-btn')
.siblings()
.removeClass('pause-btn');
```